# when i am using pojo, i am getting exception?

Tags: selenium, nullpointerexception, pojo

hi all please check my code

```
public class Sample1 extends Sample {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\Balaji-PC\\cucumber\\SamplePro\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        Sample s= new Sample1();
        WebElement d = s.getUsername();

        d.sendKeys("lsmanikandan");
        s.getPassword().sendKeys("manikandan");
    }
}
```

Please check below my pojo class

```
public class Sample {
    WebDriver driver;
    public Sample() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(id = "email")
    private WebElement username;

    @FindBy(id = "pass")
    private WebElement password;

    public WebElement getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public WebElement getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

}
```

please find below the exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.sendKeys(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.test.Sample1.main(Sample1.java:18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you are not passing your driver state from child class Sample 1 to based class Sample.

The magic is in these three points

1. Adding parametrized constructor in Child class - Sample1

   public Sample1(WebDriver driver) { super(driver); }
2. Adding parametrized constructor in Parent Class - Sample

   public Sample(WebDriver driver) {
     PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
     System.out.println("Page Factory started");
   }
3. Creating object to called page factory in Parent class by passing driver.

   Sample s = new Sample1(driver);

   ```
   public class Sample {
   WebDriver driver;
   public Sample(WebDriver driver) {
       PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
       System.out.println("Page Factory started");
   }

   @FindBy(id = "email")
   private WebElement username;

   @FindBy(id = "pass")
   private WebElement password;

   public WebElement getUsername() {
       System.out.println(username.getAttribute("data-testid"));
       return username;
   }

   public WebElement getPassword() {
       System.out.println(username.getAttribute("data-testid"));
       return password;
   }  }

   public class Sample {
       WebDriver driver;
   public Sample(WebDriver driver) {
       PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
       System.out.println("Page Factory started");
   }

   @FindBy(id = "email")
   private WebElement username;

   @FindBy(id = "pass")
   private WebElement password;

   public WebElement getUsername() {
       System.out.println(username.getAttribute("data-testid"));
       return username;
   }

   public WebElement getPassword() {
       System.out.println(username.getAttribute("data-testid"));
       return password;
   }    }
   ```

[image]

Comment: its working fine. but i don't understand much. could you please elaborate the function. i am a beginner. so i cant understand fully.

Comment: and without page factory how can i run this program. need your advise please!!!